# Can I change my stock amd fan speed?

Tags: ati, wine, hardware, fan, fancontrol

I have an amd a4-5300, and it it running loud. I remember my last amd stock fan being silent. I can't change it in my bios, and I see that it might be possible to do through Ubuntu when googling. I bet I could do it through the overclocking software that came with my MSI FM2-A75MA-E35 motherboard. Should I try that in WINE or is there a fan control program that everyone already uses with wine?

Answer (score 0):

try echoing a lower value to `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/pwm2` your fan will also have to be plugged into a fan header that supports variable speed. i believe the max is 255 so try something like `echo > 176 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/pwm2` you will need to be root

Comment: pwm2 does not exist for me in that path

Comment: The exact path depends entirely on your hardware, and usually doesn't even exist unless you have set up lm-sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Programs like that aren't going to work in WINE since they have to load a windows driver to access the hardware.

You might try installing the lm-sensors package and running the `sensors-detect` script.  It will probe for certain control chips that can be used for temperature monitoring and fan control.  If found, it will walk you through loading the correct driver.  Getting it to work often requires that you add `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to your kernel command line.  Then you can configure the `fancontrol` script to monitor temperature and adjust the fan speed.